# Using SQL Server 2008 Standard to initially start out a .com

Tags: sql-server

I know Enterprise is what I really want but when you have NO budget practically and want to start a .com then I wonder if standard would be a good choice to go with initially until you're pushed by sheer volume to go to Enterprise later with SQL Server 2008.

Thoughts?

I can't afford Enterprise but want to start a .com where I'll be getting around 2 million hits.  So anyone using Standard out there for a situation like this who is strapped and knows they'll be eventually getting a lot of hits but at first figures they can just get by with the minimum SQL Server edition until that threshold becomes unmaintainable from a basic standpoint?  For example, I don't need to be clustering until later I don't think.

Comment: The key thing here is that you *expect* ~2 million hits - you haven't yet, so use Express until you need to consider a more dedicated solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go with Sql Express if cost is an issue. OR you can join the [WebSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/web/websitespark/default.aspx) or BizSpark programs.

Comment: Both of programs; 'webspark' and 'bizspark' are very good at getting you the necessary Microsoft software to get started with an asp.net .com business.

Comment: I just wonder how scalable express is.  I mean I don't know lets say we get 1 million inserts in a year or 2.  I guess I would not need clustering yet.  I am not a guru on SQL Maintenance or extensibility.

Comment: SQL Express has a 4GB size limit and a 1GB RAM limit - I doubt it's appropriate for the scale you're intending.

Comment: The scalability of Express comes in the fact that you can upgrade directly to Standard or Enterprise once you start getting a million inserts.  Presumably by that point you'll have a business model that permits a budget for such things.

Comment: Yea, I wouldn't even consider SQL Express.  It's not meant for a heavy site like a .com.

Comment: However, if I can deal with 4 Gigs with Express then upgrade, that's not a bad way to start out a .com...free.

Comment: It looks to me like that WebSpark is only for Website development services type of businesses.  Not for a .com

Comment: My .com is not going to be one that builds out websites or applications for others, it's a social site.

Comment: ah there's a tab called startup  http://www.microsoftstartupzone.com/pages/home.aspx

Comment: That BizSpark to me looks like you don't get anything different for SQL Server.  They just show you a link to their compare page when you look at the list here: http://www.microsoftstartupzone.com/Software/Pages/Products_at_a_glance.aspx

Comment: What's the value of BizSpark if I still have to pay a crapload for SQL 2008 Standard or Enterprise when I'm just starting up and definitely do not have capital to buy such a high license.  I don't see the value at all in BizSpark.

Comment: I don't know, all I see on the BizSpark site is you can "sign up free" big fing deal.  And "you have access to software".  Ok so where's this great savings?  there are none?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using it as the backend for a website, you may want to look at the [SQL Server Web Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/web.aspx) as a cheaper option.

Comment: Thought about that.  I just wonder if indexing or other speed issues will come up in these lower editions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, I don't know if you are talking about a standard timeframe with your 2-million-hit benchmark, but here at work we are right at that count **monthly** runnning on Standard.  No issues.

Comment: No, this is an intranet site, but we have lots of traffic.

Answer (score 1):

If you trust the cloud, you might also consider [SQL Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798327/using-sql-server-2008-standard-to-initially-start-out-a-com).  It can scale on demand, so you pay based on how much you actually need.